# Path image + file upload to amazon s3 with transloadit

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, amazon-s3, transloadit

I want to upload images/videos/... to my amazon s3 bucket. I am using [Transloadit](https://transloadit.com/) to upload my files. The upload works but my images are stored like this:

> images/**ef/c3f8aa22f70265d8c12c799df0bbed/image.jpg**

I just want to have the "image.jpg" in my /images folder.
My Transloadit code:

```
$('form#MyForm').transloadit({
        wait: true,
        triggerUploadOnFileSelection: true,
        params: {
            auth: { key: "myapikey" },
            steps: {
                resize_to_125: {
                    robot: "/image/resize",
                    use: ":original",
                    width: 750,
                    height: 750
                },
                store: {
                    robot: "/s3/store",
                    key: "myket",
                    secret: "mysecretkey",
                    bucket: "mybucket/images",
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Anybody knows how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add  path in store segment:

```
 steps: {
            resize_to_125: {
                robot: "/image/resize",
                use: ":original",
                width: 750,
                height: 750
            },

 store: {
                robot: "/s3/store",
                key: "myket",
                secret: "mysecretkey",
                bucket: "mybucket",
                path: "images/image.jpg",
            }
```